# Log format not respected, logback.xml seems to be overridden

Tags: java, logback

Here are the first few line of my log:

> 2015-05-27T15:44:28+0000 Main$ {"msg":"Starting Export"}
>
> [INFO] [05/27/2015 15:44:32.215] [system-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-7] [akka://system/user/PhantomExporterManager] {"uuid":"034defdd-7cfa-4fff-be7b-687415afc70d-1432741435894","msg":"Launching job"}
>
> [INFO] [05/27/2015 15:44:32.291] [system-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5] [akka://system/user/PhantomExporterManager/PhantomExporter-1] {"account":"barkley","queryId":"603110","uuid":"034defdd-7cfa-4fff-be7b-687415afc70d-1432741435894","msg":"Export query"}

The first is correct, meaning it respects the format I defined in `logback.xml`, but the following lines are not and I do not understand what can override my `logback.xml` configuration.

Edit:
Here is my logback file:

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%date{yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ} %logger %msg %X{akkaSource} %X{akkaTimestamp}%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

And yes I'm sure that the other lines are written with the same logger that the first one.

Comment: How is your logback.xml defined? To where is it writing? if it is writing to the console, there is a possibility that your code or some library you are using is also writing to console, without utilizing logback.

Comment: Can you add the piece of code that printed those lines or perhaps the logback.xml config?

Comment: Are you sure these lines are logged via logback?